# Flask - How to load database with config from Flask config?

Tags: flask

My folder structure is the following:

```
- app.py
app
    - __init__.py
    - database.py
```

in app.py I have:

```
from app import create_app
app = create_app()
```

my **init**.py looks something like:

```
from flask import Flask
from app.database import db_session, init_db

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
        myapp = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static', static_url_path='/static', template_folder="templates")

        myapp.config.from_object('config.Config')


        db.init_app(myapp)
        migrate.init_app(myapp, db)

        # loading blueprints
        from app.core_bp import core_bp

        myapp.register_blueprint(core_bp, url_prefix='/', template_folder="templates")


return myapp
```

and database.py looks like this

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///rapporteur.db')
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,autoflush=False,bind=engine))
```

That sqlite path is currently hardcoded to raporteur.db but it should be loaded from config, because I don't want it hardcoded, but unfortunately the flask app is not yet loaded. So how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flask-sqlalchemy and set the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI in the config file.

```
class Config:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///rapporteur.db'
```

then in your **init**.py

```
 from youApp import Config

  def create_app(config_class=Config)
     app = Flask(__name__)
     app.config.from_object(config_class)
     db = SQLAlchemy()
     db.init_app(app)

     return app
```

Comment: this will not work, because the flask config gets loaded after create_engine is called. I took this approach from: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html#id4
I have also added some more context to my init file

Comment: Hm... I guess the question is. What exactely is the difference between: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html#sqlalchemy-application and https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html#id2 ?